# How to start docker container remotely

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, containers

I have a few containers, where one is a java app connecting to API and updating the Solr DB. When the update is done app and a whole container stop and start once a day (Ofelia scheduler). However, I would like to add also the possibility to start a container ("update") manually whenever I would like to. I was thinking about another container with java app with spring ../update controller, however, I don't know if it is the best solution or even how to start stopped container from java app.

```
version: '3'
    services:
          ofelia:
            container_name: update-scheduler
            (...)
          solr:
            container_name: solr
            (...)
          host:
            container_name: host
            image: nginx
            ports:
            - "80:80"
          update:
            container_name: update
            image: updateDb:latest
            ports:
              - 8086:8086
            depends_on:
              - solr
              - proxy
            command: bash -c "java -jar ***.jar
```

Comment: Might just be me, but that does sound like re-inventing the wheel. Isn't this exactly the point of having systems like Kubernetes?

Comment: You can’t do this without your “start a container” process potentially having unlimited root-level access over the host.  It’s probably better practice to directly ssh to the host and run the `docker` command you need.